# How to make an Android Web server

Tags: java, webserver

I need to use an Android device as a Web server,just as WAMP for windows and LAMP for linux, so that I can do HTTP requests using the device's IP address. I've seen many servers, but I need a good and a stable one that someone have been using.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for an app that is used as a server?

Comment: Actually I am a bit new to the concept of web services, but I need something like WAMP but for Android, a web server that allows me to do HTTP requests.

Comment: What are your requirements? Does it need to serve static content (for example HTML pages), or should it also interpret PHP files? If so, I don't think you will find what you are looking for...

Comment: I need it to allow PHP files to be executed!,is there a web server that allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using, it will allow to deploy applications from war files.

https://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/